# Extract value from a dataframe column of dictionary of lists lists and create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a dataframe with one of the columns as a list and another column as a dictionary. However, this is not consistent. It could be a single element or NULL too

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id':[1,1,1,2,3,4,4],
'shop_id':['S1','S2','S3','S2','S3','S1','S2'], 
'price_list':["{'10':['S1','S2'], '20':['S3'], '30':['S4']}","{'10':['S1','S2'], '20':['S3'], '30':['S4']}","{'10':['S1','S2'], '20':['S3'], '30':['S4']}",'50','NaN',"{'10':['S1','S2','S3'],'25':['S4']}","{'10':['S1','S2','S3'],'25':['S4']}"]})


+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+
| item_id | shop_id |                      price_list                  |
+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+
|       1 | S1      | {'10': ['S1', 'S2'], '20': ['S3'], '30': ['S4']} |
|       1 | S2      | {'10': ['S1', 'S2'], '20': ['S3'], '30': ['S4']} |
|       1 | S3      | {'10': ['S1', 'S2'], '20': ['S3'], '30': ['S4']} |
|       2 | S2      | 50                                               |
|       3 | S3      | NaN                                              |
|       4 | S1      | {'10': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3'], '25': ['S4']}         |
|       4 | S2      | {'10': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3'], '25': ['S4']}         |
+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like this to be expanded as this:

```
+---------+---------+-------+
| item_id | shop_id | price |
+---------+---------+-------+
|       1 | S1      | 10    |
|       1 | S2      | 10    |
|       1 | S3      | 20    |
|       2 | S2      | 50    |
|       3 | S3      | NaN   |
|       4 | S1      | 10    |
|       4 | S2      | 10    |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

I have tried with apply :

```
def get_price(row):
    if row['price_list'][0]=='{':
        prices = eval(row['price_list'])
        for key,value in prices.items():
            if str(row['shop_id']) in value:
                price = key
                break
            price =  np.nan
    else:
        price =  row["price_list"]
    return price


df['price'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_price(row),axis=1)
```

The dictionary elements in the price_list column are actually strings, so I might need them to be evaluated as dicts first?

But the above approach takes a lot of time since my dataframe is pretty large.

What is the best way to achieve this? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would use a list comprehension with a generator to search for the key from the value:

```
df['price'] = [next((k for k,l in d.items() if s in l), None)
               if isinstance(d, dict) else d
               for s, d in zip(df['shop_id'], df.pop('price_list'))]
```

*NB. `pop` removes the "price_list" column in place.*

Output:

```
   item_id shop_id price
0        1      S1    10
1        1      S2    10
2        1      S3    20
3        2      S2    50
4        3      S3   NaN
5        4      S1    10
6        4      S2    10
```

##### workaround if you have string representations of dicts

```
import ast

df['price'] = [next((k for k,l in ast.literal_eval(d).items() if s in l), None)
               if isinstance(d, str) and d.startswith('{') else d
               for s, d in zip(df['shop_id'], df.pop('price_list'))]
```

Comment: @mozway Thanks for the solution! 
Just one problem i see is that, my 'price_list' column is of type 'object' and all the dictionary elements in the column are srings. Is there a way I can convert them to dictionary first and then use this method?

Comment: You can convert afterwards: `df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price'])`, or use `next((float(k) for ...`

Comment: @mozway In the method you suggested, isinstance(d, dict) and d.items() does not work when the values of the column are string type. I tried evaluating them as dict using eval first:
```
dfx['price'] = [next((k for k,l in eval(d).items() for v in l if v==s), None)
               if isinstance(eval(d), dict) else d
               for s, d in zip(dfx['shop_id'], dfx['price_list'])]
```

But this is also throwing errors

Comment: @charlie, I guess you need [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Comment: So it's not like in the provided example? Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @mozway @ILS Thank you so much for your responses. 
Can you please check with this dataframe? The dict elements are string here

`
df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id':[1,1,1,2,3,4,4],
'shop_id':['S1','S2','S3','S2','S3','S1','S2'], 
'price_list':["{'10':['S1','S2'], '20':['S3'], '30':['S4']}","{'10':['S1','S2'], '20':['S3'], '30':['S4']}","{'10':['S1','S2'], '20':['S3'], '30':['S4']}",'50','NaN',"{'10':['S1','S2','S3'],'25':['S4']}","{'10':['S1','S2','S3'],'25':['S4']}"]})
`

Comment: Have you tested my update?

Comment: @mozway Thanks a lot. I tested your update. It works, but it takes similar amount of time as the apply method i was using. My dataframe has 4million rows. Is there a way I can use multiprocessing to make this faster?